# Python matplotlib legend below multiple graphs

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 2 graphs in a plot together and I want the legend to go in the blank space below both of them. For some reason it always goes right on top of one of the pies, even if I do "bottom".

Also, I've used the "title" property twice to label each graph individually. How can I move the labels below the graph as well? The title property doesn't seem to have a "loc" property.

Thanks!

```
labels = 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'
fracsQuads = [6, 14, 1, 79]
fracsTrips = [11, 16, 7, 66]
colors=['Goldenrod', 'LimeGreen', 'Crimson', 'DeepSkyBlue']

explode=(0, 0, 0, 0)

# Make square figures and axes

the_grid = GridSpec(1, 2)

plt.subplot(the_grid[0, 0], aspect=1)

plt.pie(fracsQuads, autopct='%1.0f%%', colors=colors, pctdistance=1.2)

plt.title('Four knockouts')
plt.subplot(the_grid[0, 1], aspect=1)


plt.pie(fracsTrips, explode=explode, autopct='%.0f%%', colors=colors, pctdistance=1.2)
plt.title('Three knockouts')

#plt.legend(labels, loc='best')

font = {'family' : 'normal',
        'weight' : 'normal',
        'size'   : 14}

matplotlib.rc('font', **font)

plt.show()

plt.savefig('pythonFigureTest.png', facecolor='white', transparent=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that you are not labeling the axes. Therefore, the legend will be placed always with respect to the right plot because this was the last created axis.
You can move to legend box by hand with `bbox_to_anchor`. In addition, I removed the titles and put the text by hand below the plots using `figtext()`.

The following code should do it:

```
font = {'family' : 'normal',
        'weight' : 'normal',
        'size'   : 14}

rcParams.update(font)

labels = 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'
fracsQuads = [6, 14, 1, 79]
fracsTrips = [11, 16, 7, 66]
colors=['Goldenrod', 'LimeGreen', 'Crimson', 'DeepSkyBlue']

explode=(0, 0, 0, 0)

# Make square figures and axes

the_grid = GridSpec(1, 2)

ax1 = plt.subplot(the_grid[0, 0], aspect=1)
ax2 = plt.subplot(the_grid[0, 1], aspect=1)

ax1.pie(fracsQuads, autopct='%1.0f%%', colors=colors, pctdistance=1.2)
ax2.pie(fracsTrips, explode=explode, autopct='%.0f%%', colors=colors, pctdistance=1.2)

plt.figtext(0.19,0.2,'Four knockouts')
plt.figtext(0.61,0.2,'Three knockouts')

ax1.legend(labels, loc='lower center',bbox_to_anchor=(1.1, -0.1),
                 prop={'size':11})

plt.show()
```

I used small fontsizes in the legend box such that it fits nicely inbetween. In case you have longer text you may have to fiddle around with the numbers.